# Lumen Installer Bug?

Tags: lumen

I am having a problem trying to install the lumen installer on my **El Capitan** computer. This is the command line I launch:

```
composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer"
```

I also tried it as `sudo` but it gives me the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Here is the complete output of the command:

```
Changed current directory to /Users/mmarteau/.composer
Using version ^1.0 for laravel/lumen-installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/lumen-installer v1.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/process v3.0.1
    - Installation request for laravel/lumen-installer ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/lumen-installer[v1.0.0, v1.0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v3.0.1
    - laravel/lumen-installer v1.0.0 requires symfony/process ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.11, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.12, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.13, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.14, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.15, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.16, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.17, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.18, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.19, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.20, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.21, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.22, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.23, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.24, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.25, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.26, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.27, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.28, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.29, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.30, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.31, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.32, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.33, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.34, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.35, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.36, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.37, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.11, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.12, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.10, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.11, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.12, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.13, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.2, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.3, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.4, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.5, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.6, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.7, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.8, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.9, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.8.0, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.8.1, v3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.8.2, v3.0.1].
    - Installation request for symfony/process == 3.0.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v3.0.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I Googled it a little and self updated composer but nothing changes, if someone can help, it would be cool :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Mac trying to install the lumen installer. Now I found a solution by removing the old .composer directory from my home directory. Then running the composer command to install the lumen installer works without problems:

```
composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer"
```

Comment: hi, I tried that but didn't help
this is what I have

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/lumen-installer v1.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.3.0
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.2.0
    - Installation request for laravel/lumen-installer ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/lumen-installer[v1.0.0, v1.0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.1.1